# Can I adjust a weighted average of uniforms to be uniform?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have uniformly-distributed random variables $x_i$ satisfying

$$0\le x_i\le 1$$

I take a weighted mean of these using weights $w_i$ satisfying

$$0\le w_i\le 1$$
$$\sum w_i=1$$

The naive weighted mean is

$$\hat{x}=\sum w_ix_i$$

but $\hat{x}$ no longer has a uniform distribution.

What smooth adjustment $X=f(\hat{x})$ can I make such that $X$ has uniform distribution?

Comment: If $F$ is the cumulative distribution function of $\hat x$, then $F(\hat x)$ is uniform on $[0,1]$. See [probability integral transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_integral_transform).

Comment: So what is the CDF of $\hat{x}$?